# !string.equals(string) turns false result

Tags: java, string, if-statement, java.util.scanner

In a part of my program, I put a while loop to repeatedly ask for inputs. There is an option to type in the letter "F" and break the loop.
This is my program:

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        ArrayList Numbers = new ArrayList();
        while (x==0) {
            System.out.println("Type your number:");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (s.equals("f") || s.equals("F")) {
                x = 1;
            }
            else if (!s.equals("f") && !s.equals("F")) {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                Numbers.add(n);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I type some numbers and then type "F". I see this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "F"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Example.main(Example.java:13)
```

I believe the String "F" can pass through my *else if* but I don't know why. How can I solve this?

Comment: In the code, you do not comapre a `String` against a `String`, but a `Scanner` against a `String`. This will always return `false`.

Comment: @Turing85 What's the best way to convert a Scanner into a String?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: You don't need the condition after the else, because you've already checked if the character is "f", so the else condition is called when this is false. This assumes, however, that you're checking on a String rather than a Scanner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing a string with a Scanner obj. Lets see how a scanner object works in java.

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
String myInput = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
```

Then you can compare your `myInput` to the character 'f' or 'F'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare a scanner object with a string. You will need to take some input using scanner and then you can compare that input with other types.
Try running this code.

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    ArrayList Numbers = new ArrayList();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (x==0) {
        System.out.println("Type your number:");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if (s.equals("f") || s.equals("F")) {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (!s.equals("f") && !s.equals("F")) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
            Numbers.add(n);
        }
    }
    
}}
```